# Embedding javassist dependency breaks OSGi bundle

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, maven-bundle-plugin, embedded-osgi

I am trying an embedded Felix scenario. While loading a bundle from the embedded OSGi container (Apache Felix), I am getting the following error.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve test.bundle-attempt [50](R 50.0): missing requirement [test.bundle-attempt [50](R 50.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jdi.connect) Unresolved requirements: [[test.bundle-attempt [50](R 50.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jdi.connect)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4362)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2277)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1535)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

With some trial and error, I have found that introducing `javassist` causes the error.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am trying to embed the dependency.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.snc.TestPluginsActivator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Export-Package>com.snc</Export-Package>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Any suggestions on the reason why I am getting this error ?

Comment: Instead of embedding the javassist jar, you can try deploy the javassist jar along with your own bundle to Felix. I verified that the javassist jar is packaged as an OSGi bundle, and does _not_import any `com.sun` packages.

Comment: @gjoranv As per [javassit POM] (https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/blob/master/pom.xml), `com.sun.jdi` is neither imported nor exported. The dependency for `com.sun` is resolved from the system path. So, I wonder why there is a wiring problem. I understand the alternative option and I have tried it myself however my current scenario needs embedding of the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the **javassist** artifact is dependent on jar

```
<groupId>com.sun</groupId>
<artifactId>tools</artifactId>
```

and the above jar is marked as optional in the **pom** of **javassist** and the package `com.sun.jdi.connect` which is unresolved in your example belongs to the above jar, **tools**, that I mentioned.

When trying get the transtive dependencies of Embed-dependencies, maven-bundle-plugin doesn't mark the packages of those transtive optional dependencies as optional in **MANIFEST.MF** file and it is trying to resolve the dependencies when the bundle is installed. As the optional transtive dependencies are not included in the class path of the bundle it is throwing the error saying `Unresolved requirements` while starting the bundle.

To resolve the issue you can mark  those dependencies as optional in the **pom** of bundle.